# Pascal's Triangle in AEC

Tags: assembly, compiler

So, I am trying to make people interested in my [compiler](https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler) project (in the early stages of development) by making some simple and clear programs in my programming language. Here is my implementation of the Pascal's Triangle in it. Do you think it's clear? If so, what do you think might be unclear to an average programmer?

```
;Pascal's triangle
AsmStart ;Inline assembly in AEC starts with "AsmStart" and ends with "AsmEnd".
    macro pushIntegerToTheSystemStack decimalNumber ;This is why I've chosen FlatAssembler for the back-end of my compiler: powerful and easy-to-use preprocessor.
    {
        sub esp,4 ;"esp" is the CPU register which points right below the data at the top of the system stack.
        fld dword [decimalNumber]
        fistp dword [esp] ;"fistp" is the x86 assembly language directive for converting decimal numbers to integers.
    }
    macro pushPointerToTheSystemStack pointer
    {
        sub esp,4
        lea ebx,[pointer]
        mov [esp],ebx
    }
    macro pushStringToTheSystemStack string
    {
        sub esp,4
        mov dword [esp],string
    }
    format PE console ;"PE" means 32-bit Windows executable.
    entry start

    include 'win32a.inc' ;FlatAssembler macros for importing functions from DLLs.
    section '.text' code executable

    start:
    jmp howManyRowsString$
    howManyRowsString:
        db "How many rows of Pascal's triangle do you want to be printed?",10,0 ;10 is '\n', and 0 is '\0'.
    howManyRowsString$:
    pushStringToTheSystemStack howManyRowsString
    call [printf] ;printf(howManyRowsString)
    jmp theFloatSymbol$
    theFloatSymbol:
        db "%f",0
    theFloatSymbol$:
    pushPointerToTheSystemStack numberOfRows
    pushStringToTheSystemStack theFloatSymbol
    call [scanf] ;scanf(theFloatSymbol,&numberOfRows)
AsmEnd
currentRow := 0
While currentRow < numberOfRows | currentRow = numberOfRows
    AsmStart
        jmp currentRowString$
        currentRowString:
            db "Row #%d:",9,0 ;9 is '\t' (the tabulator).
        currentRowString$:
        pushIntegerToTheSystemStack currentRow
        pushStringToTheSystemStack currentRowString
        call [printf] ;printf(currentRowString,currentRow)
    AsmEnd
    currentColumn:=0
    While currentColumn < currentRow | currentColumn = currentRow
        If currentColumn = 0
            array (currentRow * numberOfRows + currentColumn) := 1 ;When I haven't programmed the compiler to deal with 2-dimensional arrays...
        ElseIf currentColumn = currentRow
            array (currentRow * numberOfRows + currentColumn) := 1  
        Else
            numberImmediatelyAbove := array ( (currentRow - 1) * numberOfRows + currentColumn)
            numberBeforeTheImmediatelyAboveOne := array ( (currentRow - 1) * numberOfRows + currentColumn - 1)
            array (currentRow * numberOfRows + currentColumn) := numberBeforeTheImmediatelyAboveOne + numberImmediatelyAbove
        EndIf
        numberToBePrinted := array (currentRow * numberOfRows + currentColumn)
        AsmStart
            jmp integerSignWithTabulator$
            integerSignWithTabulator:
                db "%.0f",9,0 ;"%.0f\t", "%.0f" means for "printf" to round the decimal number to the nearest integer.
            integerSignWithTabulator$:
            fld dword [numberToBePrinted]
            fstp qword [esp] ;"qword" means "double", because "printf" from "MSVCRT.DLL" can't print "float" which hasn't been converted to "double". When writing in Assembly, you need to deal with that kind of annoying stuff.
            pushStringToTheSystemStack integerSignWithTabulator
            call [printf] ;printf(integerSignWithTabulator,numberToBePrinted)
        AsmEnd
        currentColumn := currentColumn + 1
    EndWhile
    AsmStart
        jmp newLineString$
        newLineString:
            db 10,0 ;"\n"
        newLineString$:
        pushStringToTheSystemStack newLineString
        call [printf] ;printf(newLineString)
    AsmEnd
    currentRow := currentRow + 1
EndWhile
AsmStart
pushStringToTheSystemStack pauseString
call [system] ;system(pauseString), the "Press any key to continue..." message so that the console window doesn't immediately close.
invoke exit,0 ;exit(0)

pauseString db "PAUSE",0

section '.rdata' readable writable
    result dd ? ;A variable used internally by the AEC compiler.
    numberOfRows dd ?
    currentRow dd ?
    currentColumn dd ?
    numberBeforeTheImmediatelyAboveOne dd ?
    numberImmediatelyAbove dd ?
    numberToBePrinted dd ?
    array dd 30000 DUP(?)

section '.idata' data readable import
    library msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll' ;"Microsoft Visual C Runtime Library", available as "C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll" on Windows 98 and newer.
        import msvcrt,printf,'printf',system,'system',exit,'exit',scanf,'scanf',clock,'clock'
AsmEnd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it very confusing that you consider all of this assembly as *inline* assembly. I see the start and exit of a regular FASM assembly program, 2 things I don't expect to find in *inline* assembly.

Am I correct when I say that your high level language only uses single precision float variables? If not then variables like *numberOfRows*, *currentRow*, and *currentColumn* should be treated like dword integers for speed and frankly because that's what they truly are.

> ```
> numberBeforeTheImmediatelyAboveOne dd ?
> numberImmediatelyAbove dd ?
> ```

While using descriptive names is encouraged, having source lines that are much longer than the visible screen's width makes reading a lot more difficult. Perhaps you could make use of FASM's line continuation character `\` ?

> ```
> While currentRow < numberOfRows | currentRow = numberOfRows
> ```

Why the OR operator? Does your project not have the compound `<=` operator?
If available then simply write: `While currentRow <= numberOfRows`.
If not available then you could invert the condition to: `While numberOfRows > currentRow`.

### This is wrong

> ```
> fld dword [numberToBePrinted]
> fstp qword [esp]
> ```

Here you convert a single precision float into a double precision float, but you forget to reserve space on the stack!

```
sub esp, 8                  <<<< Making room on the stack
fld dword [numberToBePrinted]
fstp qword [esp]
```

### Optimizing for codesize where speed doesn't matter at all

Why do you prefer those macros so much? `pushPointerToTheSystemStack numberOfRows` is just `push numberOfRows`. What could be simpler?

The `call` instruction can do some work for you. You don't need to use the `pushStringToTheSystemStack` macro:

```
call howManyRowsString
db "How many rows of Pascal's triangle do you want to be printed?",10,0
howManyRowsString:
call [printf]
add esp, 4                  <<<< Don't you need to cleanup the stack with msvcrt ?

push numberOfRows           <<<< Simple
call theFloatSymbol
db "%f",0
theFloatSymbol:
call [scanf]
add esp, 8                  <<<< Don't you need to cleanup the stack with msvcrt ?
```

Comment: Yes, for now, the only data types my program supports are Float32 and Float32Array. I didn't know about cleaning up the stack after calling MSVCRT, thanks for letting me know.